# Problem in displaying localized labels in Dart

Tags: flutter

I am not able to set localization in my app.

I am trying to add language settings and associated localization in my app. I am able to get-set the language option. I am using 'intl' plug-in for internationalization. My code looks like below in pretty much all the UI .dart files.

```
AppTranslations.of(context).accountNumber +
                    " ${accountDetails.accountNumber}",
```

The getters is set as :

```
String get accountNumber => _text("account_number");

String _text(String key) {
    return _localisedValues[key] ?? _defaultLocaleValues[key];
  }
```

I've also placed json files containing localized labels in 3 different languages. However, it seems there is some instantiation problem of the locazation plug-in. The code doesn't go the getter line.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please can you show where you are using this parts of code, that we can understand what is going on there?

Comment: In the individual UI files, I've AppTranslations.of(context).____ labels. These labels are maintained in app_translations.dart. And the locale_provider.dart provides sets the locale. And the assets folder contains the individual JSON files having localized labels.

Answer (score 2):

`AppTranslations.of(context)` is a standard way of accessing the localised labels. You are right about the instantiation. If the program doesn't go to the getter line them it means, there's a problem in somewhere in the initial part of the code. It could be in the main.dart.

Check where you are initialising LocalStorageProvider(). In case it is not initialised then that's the problem. Assuming you are using a MaterialApp, try the below suggestion then :
Wrap the MaterialApp with LocalStorageProvider(). I mean, in the main widget build, return LocalStorageProvider() and pass your existing code of MaterialApp() as a child to it. Sample below (Please ignore the theme etc since I just copied the code from one of my app) :

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    LocalStorage localStorage = LocalStorage();
    return LocalStorageProvider(
      localStorage: localStorage,
      child: LocaleProvider(
        localStorage: localStorage,
        localeWrapper: LocaleWrapper(),
        child: Builder(
          builder: (context) {
            return AnimatedBuilder(
              animation: LocaleProvider.of(context).localeWrapper,
              builder: (context, _) {
                return MaterialApp(
                  onGenerateTitle: (context) =>
                      AppTranslations.of(context).appName,
                  locale: LocaleProvider.of(context).locale,
                  title: "App Title",
                  theme: ThemeData(
                    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                  home: MapsDemo(),
                  localizationsDelegates: [
                    AppTranslationsDelegate(
                      LocaleProvider.of(context).supportedLanguagesCodes,
                    ),
                    GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
                    GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
                  ],
                  supportedLocales: LocaleProvider.of(context).supportedLocales,
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Why do we need AnimatedBuilder in between MaterialApp and LocalStorageProvider ?

Comment: No, you don't. Feel free to remove it from the code above. (Like I said, I just copy pasted this code from one of my app. Feel free to remove whatever you don't need).